# show top menu bar to left side in magento2

Tags: magento2.3, topmenu

I want to replace the top menu bar to the left side 
i have written this code in my theme default.xml

```
<body>
<referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" 
name="store.menu" group="navigation-sections" 
template="Magento_Theme::html/container.phtml">
<arguments>
<argument name="title" translate="true" 
xsi:type="string">Menu</argument>
</arguments>
</block>
</referenceContainer>
 </body>
```

but nothing change

Answer (score 0):

Strange that there is no full answer anywhere on this as it took me ages to work it out!

1 - Make sure you main pages (such as the home page) have a sidebar.

> In admin: Content -> Pages and under the layout column change all to '2 columns with left bar'

2 - Make your child theme and activate it : https://meetanshi.com/blog/create-child-theme-in-magento-2/

3 - In your default.xml file put this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <move element="catalog.topnav" destination="sidebar.main" before="-" />
    <move element="catalog.leftnav" destination="sidebar.main" after="catalog.topnav" />
</body>
```

The first move puts the top navigation in the side bar. The second move makes sure it appears before Layered Navigation on category pages